# Can we take of benefit of using transfer learning while training a word2vec models?

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, word2vec

I am looking to find a pre-trained weights of an already trained models like **Google News data** etc. I found it hard to train a new model with enough amount (10 GB etc) of data for myself. So, I want to take benefit from transfer learning in which I would able to get pre-trained layer weights and retrain those weights on my domain specific words. So, definitely it will take relatively less time in training. Any sort of help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can take benefit of pre-trained models. Most famous one being the GoogleNewsData trained model which you can find here.

Pre-trained word and phrase vectors https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?usp=sharing

You can then load the vectors in binary format in your model using gensim as shown below.

```
>>> model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('/tmp/vectors.txt', binary=False)  # C text format
>>> model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('/tmp/vectors.bin', binary=True)  # C binary format
```

Here is a different pre-built model for English Wikipedia:

https://github.com/idio/wiki2vec/raw/master/torrents/enwiki-gensim-word2vec-1000-nostem-10cbow.torrent

Source: https://github.com/idio/wiki2vec/

Using a prebuilt model

```
Get python 2.7
Install gensim: pip install gensim
uncompress downloaded model: tar -xvf model.tar.gz
Load model in gensim:
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec.load("path/to/word2vec/en.model")
model.similarity('woman', 'man')
```

You can also use Stanford NLP Glove

- http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/
- https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe

Here is a great compilation of pre-trained word2vec models.

- https://github.com/3Top/word2vec-api#where-to-get-a-pretrained-models

Some additional pre-trained models:

- http://www.zuccon.net/ntlm.html
- https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/

More on gensim and code here:  https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

Quora forum with a similar questions

- https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-pre-trained-models-of-word2vec-and-sentence2vec-trained-on-Wikipedia-or-other-large-text-corpus
- https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-some-pre-trained-word-vectors-for-natural-language-processing-understanding

Comment: Okay, that is great piece of information good work. But, can i use pre-trained models layer weights to initialize a new model and then further tune that model with my sentences?

Comment: @Nomi Yes. From [gensim documentation] (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) , once you load the model, `model = Word2Vec.load(fname)  # you can continue training with the loaded model!`

Comment: Documentation link above mentions: "NOTE: It is impossible to continue training the vectors loaded from the C format because hidden weights, vocabulary frequency and the binary tree is missing."

Answer (score 3):

[*Distributed representations (Glove)*](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) based on training on a large corpus are directly available from Stanford NLP group. You can use those word embeddings directly in your application (instead of using 1 hot encoded vectors and then training the network to get the embeddings). If your task is not too specialized starting with this set of embeddings will work well in practice.

It will **save you from training an additional $m \times V$ number of parameters** where $V$ is the vocabulary size and  $m$ is the dimension of the embedding space you want to project into.

Comment: But, i want to initialize my new word2vec model with pre-trained model weights. Is it possible to use already pre-trained model layer weights to initialize new model. After initialization i want to train that model with new sentences. is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can. However I don't think the weight matrix is available publicly

Comment: Yup, right...? If we train a model ourselves and try to access the access the   trained model weights using Gensim library. Is it possible

Comment: Not sure about gensim but because it's a parameter to be optimized most software should allow it

Comment: @HrishikeshGanu Is this link still working? 

https://github.com/idio/wiki2vec/raw/master/torrents/enwiki-gensim-word2vec-1000-nostem-10cbow.torrent

Source: https://github.com/idio/wiki2vec/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this paper [[PDF]](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W15-1830). The main focus is about NER task but the idea is the same - take pre-trained word2vec vectors and adapt them for a specific application.

Many common neural network based applications for NLP frequently start with pre-trained vectors. For example a very recent paper [[PDF]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.01354) (NER and POS tagging tasks) does just this.

Answer (score 1):

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec 
# Word2Vec is full model which is trainable but takes larger memory

from gensim.models import KeyedVectors  
# KeyedVectors is reduced vector model which is NOT trainable but takes less memory

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True) #load pretrained google w2v 

sen1 = 'w1 w2 w3'    
sen2 = 'word1 word2 word3'    
sentences = [[word for word in sen1.split()],[word for word in sen2.split()]]    
total_examples = model_2.corpus_count    

model_2 = Word2Vec(size=300, min_count=1) #initiate a full model    
model_2.build_vocab(sentences) #add words in training dataset

#load words from pretrained google dataset    
model_2.build_vocab([list(model.vocab.keys())], update=True)    
model_2.intersect_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True, lockf=1.0)

#retrain pretrained w2v from new dataset    
model_2.train(sentences, total_examples=total_examples, epochs=model_2.iter)
```